# Cassandra table TTL

Tags: cassandra

Does Cassandra have some keyspace policy, specifying something like a TTL for a table, which when set, the whole table is dropped/deleted after the period of time? The TTL set on the whole table deletes only the records in the table, but I need the whole table to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of such a request or need. Very interesting. Cassandra does not have any functionality that I know of to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot set a TTL at a table level. This practice is not encouraged generally. If you really want to do such a thing, you will have to do it using the driver.